# Going out of bounds on a loop?

Tags: vba, excel

Apparently Im going out of bounds on my array. I get the "subscript out of range error" everytime I try to read a column. Tried to debug it and run it in another column and it absolutely works, but not on this specific one. Any hint?

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim curp, fname, lname1, lname2, gender As String, i, pos As Long, asciinum As String, f As Long, validar As Boolean, fechaNac As Date

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        For f = 2 To Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
            curp = Cells(f, "L").Value2
            fname = Cells(f, "F").Value2
            lname1 = Cells(f, "I").Value2
            lname2 = Cells(f, "J").Value
            gender = Cells(f, "k").Value2
            fechaNac = Cells(f, "P").Value2
' works           validar = CheckFirstLetter(lname1, curp, 1, f)
' works           validar = CheckFirstVowel(lname1, curp, 2, f)
            validar = CheckFirstLetter(lname2, curp, 3, f)
'            validar = CheckFirstLetter(fname, curp, 4)
'            validar = CheckDate(fechaNac, curp, 5)
'            validar = CheckGender(gender, curp, 11)
'            validar = CheckConsonant(lname1, curp, 12, 2)
'            validar = CheckConsonant(lname2, curp, 13, 2)
'            pos = posVowel(fname)
'            validar = CheckConsonant(fname, curp, 14, pos)
            If (validar = True) Then
            Cells(f, "N") = "Valido"
            Else: Cells(f, "N") = "No Valido"
            End If
        Next f
    End With
End Sub

Function CheckFirstLetter(mystring, text, indexCurp, index) As Boolean
            Dim outStr, asciinum, vocal, vocal2 As String, ary As Variant, i As Long
            ary = Split(mystring, " ")
            vocal = LCase(ary(LBound(ary)))   Breaks in this line
            vocal2 = LCase(ary(UBound(ary)))
            If (vocal = "de" Or vocal = "del") Then
            vocal = vocal2
            End If
            outStr = LCase(Mid(text, indexCurp, 1))
            asciinum = LCase(Mid(vocal, 1, 1))
            Cells(index, "M") = vocal
            Cells(index, "O") = vocal2
            If (asciinum = outStr) Then
                CheckFirstLetter = True
                Else: CheckFirstLetter = False
                End If
End Function
```

The reason for 2 lbound and ubound is because sometimes the strings come with different length and I just want to take the last word. But it breaks on that particular space. Im guessing it is because Im not pointing to the right cell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I went through and fixed some of the stuff that was broken. Any time you are declaring variables like:

```
Dim SomeVariable1, SomeVariable2, SomeVariable3 as String
```

It is as if saying:

```
Dim SomeVariable1 as Variant, SomeVariable2 as Variant, SomeVariable3 as String
```

Listing all of the declarations on the same line only prevents you from needing to repeat the scope, not the type.

Also, you do a lot of:

```
Cells(f, "K").Value
```

But this reference is unqualified, even though it is within the With block. Put a period before these to qualify them.

Lastly, define the variable types that should be expected for your function.

```
CheckFirstLetter(mystring, text, indexCurp, index) As Boolean
```

Is the same as

```
CheckFirstLetter(mystring as Variant, text as Variant, indexCurp as Variant, index as Variant) As Boolean
```

Which means I can pass whatever I want to in, and there wont be an issue. I suspect that all the variants in your subroutines are the issues. See the fixed code below:

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim curp As String
    Dim fname As String
    Dim lname1 As String
    Dim lname2 As String
    Dim gender As String

```
Dim i As Long
Dim pos As Long
Dim asciinum As String
Dim f As Long ' Why jump back to f if you have i declared? It doesnt make a difference, but usually the next logical choice is j
Dim validar As Boolean
Dim fechaNac As Date

With Worksheets("sheet1")
    For f = 2 To Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
        ' Be sure to qualify ALL references.
        curp = .Cells(f, "L").Value2
        fname = .Cells(f, "F").Value2
        lname1 = .Cells(f, "I").Value2
        lname2 = .Cells(f, "J").Value
        gender = .Cells(f, "k").Value2
        fechaNac = .Cells(f, "P").Value2
' works           validar = CheckFirstLetter(lname1, curp, 1, f)
' works           validar = CheckFirstVowel(lname1, curp, 2, f)
             validar = CheckFirstLetter(lname2, curp, 3, f)
'            validar = CheckFirstLetter(fname, curp, 4)
'            validar = CheckDate(fechaNac, curp, 5)
'            validar = CheckGender(gender, curp, 11)
'            validar = CheckConsonant(lname1, curp, 12, 2)
'            validar = CheckConsonant(lname2, curp, 13, 2)
'            pos = posVowel(fname)
'            validar = CheckConsonant(fname, curp, 14, pos)
            If (validar = True) Then
                .Cells(f, "N") = "Valido"
            Else
                .Cells(f, "N") = "No Valido"
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function CheckFirstLetter(mystring As String, text As String, indexCurp As Long, index As Long) As Boolean
            Dim i As Long

            Dim ary As Variant
            ary = Split(mystring, " ")

            Dim vocal As String
            vocal = LCase(ary(LBound(ary)))   'Breaks in this line

            Dim vocal2 As String
            vocal2 = LCase(ary(UBound(ary)))

            If (vocal = "de" Or vocal = "del") Then
                vocal = vocal2
            End If

            Dim outStr As String
            outStr = LCase(Mid(text, indexCurp, 1))

            Dim asciinum As String
            asciinum = LCase(Mid(vocal, 1, 1))

            ' Qualify these cell references
            Cells(index, "M") = vocal
            Cells(index, "O") = vocal2

            ' I dont know if the parentheses are needed here, I just like them
            CheckFirstLetter = (asciinum = outStr)

'            If (asciinum = outStr) Then
'                CheckFirstLetter = True
'            Else
'                CheckFirstLetter = False
'            End If
End Function
```

Lastly, don't try to be cute with your if blocks:

```
If True = True Then: Debug.Print True
Else: Debug.Print False
End If
```

Saves you two lines, and it makes it more difficult to read and debug your code. You can also directly assign the boolean result of a comparison to a boolean variable. Both of these work:

```
Result = True = False
Result = (True = False)
```